# Google maps api v3 - close infowindow from external link

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a map with sidebar listings and would like to close infowindow from button in sidebar.

```
<div class="close" onclick="">X</div>
<div id="map"></div>
```

I currently have this which closes infowindow by clicking anywhere in the map.

```
     google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(){
       infowindow.close(map, marker);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

The infowindow `close` function doesn't take any parameters.

```html
<div class="close" onclick="closeInfowindow()">X</div>
```

```js
function closeInfowindow() {
  infowindow.close();
}
```